# Form.HandleCreated Event Never Occurs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nbug

As it was requested, I've put up a small internal log viewer for one of my open-source projects (self descriptive image below). While doing so, I had a very strange problem where the newly created window's HandleCreated event does not occur at all. I'm watching this event to make sure that handle is created before invoking any controls.

[image: NBug Internal Log Viewer]

Below is the problematic code (the static constructor). Does anybody have a workaround for this because none of the usual tricks (like var a = form.Handle;) to force the creation of the handle do not help at all.

```
internal partial class InternalLogViewer : Form
{
    static InternalLogViewer()
    {
        viewer = new InternalLogViewer();
        formShown = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        viewer.HandleCreated += (sender, e) => formShown.Set();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => viewer.ShowDialog());
        formShown.WaitOne(); // ToDo: This needs a workaround as it waits for an eternity
    }

    private static InternalLogViewer viewer;
    private static ManualResetEvent formShown;

    public static void LogEntry(string message, LoggerCategory category)
    {
        viewer.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            viewer.InternalLogEntry(message, category);
        });
    }

    internal InternalLogViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.NBug_icon_16;
        this.notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.NBug_icon_16;
    }

    internal void InternalLogEntry(string message, LoggerCategory category)
    {
        this.loggerListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { category.ToString().Remove(0, 4), DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), message }));
    }
}
```

Edit: Code is taken from [NBug](http://www.nbusy.com/projects/nbug) library.

Comment: possibly related to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx

Comment: Oh my, moving the contents of the static constructor into a separate function and calling that for initialization actually does work. I honestly couldn't imagine such a deadlock!

Comment: @Dmitry: looks like you found the solution, please post it as an "answer" below so readers can know there's a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to [static constructor deadlocks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx).

Comment: That is a broken link